# Unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13: not found when running sbt 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala project consisting of a few ones. I decided to start using sbt `0.13`. Here is `~/sbt/repositories`:

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

But still I get an error:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13

    ==== local: tried

      /home/alex/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried

      http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== maven-central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13/sbt-0.13.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/alex/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13
```

If I remove this file then the error remains.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I decided to start using sbt 0.13"*? Did you download sbt 0.13?

Comment: Did you mean ~/.sbt/repositories instead of ~/sbt/repositories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `0.13.1`.

Put the following in `project/build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

You will probably need the `0.13` sbt launcher as well. See [sbt Getting-Started - Setup](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html)

Comment: I did, but I got another error: `[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected ` -- `JLine incompatibility detected.  Check that the sbt launcher is version 0.13.x or later`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are experiencing version mismatch issue.

If you have modified your `project/build.properties` to include `sbt.version=0.13.0`, it could mean that you are using wrong launcher.

Try running

```
sbt sbt-version
```

and check if the version matches your sbt version in `project/build.properties`.

Comment: How do you change what launcher you're using?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when first installing openjdk-9-jdk and then openjdk-8-jdk on Ubuntu.

I ended up uninstalling both, `rm -rf`ing `/etc/ssl/certs/java` and `/etc/java-*`, reinstalling `openjdk-8-jdk` and running `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`, which fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Using Ubuntu 18.04 and having installed open-jdk 8 and 11. I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250) to uninstall Java. Then I installed open-jdk-8-jdk again and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

**Two steps only**

1. Update the certificates using

   ```
   $ update-ca-certificates -f
   ```
2. Enter

   ```
   $ sbt
   ```

It will fetch the requisite files, if connected to internet.

Comment: Does the answer really belong to this question? I do not see anything related to certificates in it.