# IntelliJ throws sbt errors while doing the build

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I am facing this error while importing a  spark project from GIT

I dont know how to proceed with this

```
Error while importing sbt project:

 Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.17  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17

==== local: tried

C:\Users\omega\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.17\ivys\ivy.xml

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

C:\Users\omega\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.17\jars\sbt.jar

==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/ivy-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/ivy-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/mvn-repositories/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/mvn-repositories/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== my-sbt-ivy-snapshots3: tried

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar
 ==== my-sbt-ivy-snapshots2: tried

 https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

 -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== typesafe-releases: tried

https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/typesafe/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

 https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/typesafe/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

 ==== typesafe-ivy-releases/: tried

  https://nexus.rxcorp.com:8081/nexus/repository/Typesafe-Ivy-Releases/org.scala- 
 sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

 ==== Maven Central: tried

 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

 -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

  :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17: not found

 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



   :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
    Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
       Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A solution: use version `0.13.18` of SBT instead. That is still on the
  [repository](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html), while version `0.13.17` has already been deleted.

  Just change the version within your `project/build.properties:` to

  `sbt.version=0.13.18`. As mentioned [in that other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19805716/5032130) you also
  need to update the sbt launcher to version `0.13.18`.
- Recommended solution: Try changing the sbt version to `1.X.X`. Versions
  `0.13.X` are no longer supported (see [in scala-sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html)). Note
  that SBT 1.X.X introduced breaking changes, so you would need to
  follow [their guide for migrating from 0.13.X](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html).